# Resolve - Blur the edges of an inserted clip

Tags: davinci-resolve

I am totally new to DaVinci Resolve. I have included a small video on top of another footage, in the bottom right corner. How can I blur the edges of this inserted video?

I am able to blur the **content** of the video, what is inside, but I would like to blur the edges/border of the small video, so it blends better on top of the other one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer:

- Go to `Color` at the bottom.
- Select the clip you want to modify (the small video on top).
- Add your usual nodes as needed.
- Right click and `Add Alpha Output`. This will create a new blue terminator.
- Right click and add a new `Corrector` node and use the rectangle, ellipse, or whatever shape you need to define the transparent/opaque regions.
- Connect the previous nodes to the recently created node. Now link the green and blue points. This will make an alpha channel, making the region you marked as transparent/opaque.
- If you need to use the same ALPHA node in other clips, you can create a `Shared node` that can be reused in other clips. Instead of adding a `Corrector` node this time, use your shared node.

See the image below for a clarification:

[image: description]

Source: